# Got the error while importing sentencetransformer

Tags: python, nlp

Unable to solve this error, somebody plz help

Tried this...
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

and it gaved me this error...

```
ImportError: numpy>=1.17 is required for a normal functioning of this module, but found numpy==1.16.5.
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git main
```

Comment: Have you read the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update numpy (1.21.5) then I realized that numpy-base version is below 1.17, I updated numpy-base version and it resolved.